# VBA - Printing in the next column

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop, yahoo-api

I am using stock tickers to fetch the last price from yahoo finance (this is no problem). However, I am having difficulty printing them in the column beside it. On occasion I will have an options symbol (AAPL161007...) which will return "NA", when this happens I would like it to just print nothing. the tickers range from row 6 to 25. The program keeps getting stuck at the line "With Active sheet..)
The code for last trade in yahoo is "l1". Also,the AAPL ticker won't be the only ticker in the column. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
Sub variables()

Dim qurl As String
Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("K6:K25")


For Each cell In rng

    ARL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + "AAPL" + "&f=" + "l1"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & ARL, Destination:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)))


        .Name = "qtActiveRange" & Rnd()
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        End With

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `ARL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + "AAPL" + "&f=" + "l1"` should be `ARL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & cell.Value & "&f=l1"` and `Destination:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))` should be `Destination:=cell.Offset(0, 2)`, but I'm not sure how to suppress the "N/A" which is your main question.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:="URL;" & ARL, Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
```